# OpenStreetMap > force display of village labels

Tags: openstreetmap

Working on an OpenStreetMap implementation...
One of the, **very annoying** constraints is the max-zoom level has to be locked at `11`

But I would need to be able to somehow force the map to display the village labels that only appear at zoom level `12` and `13`.

Tried playing around with MapBox but that did not do the trick...

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to get this done ?

Thanks a lot in advance
dgoosens

Comment: Where did you experience this zoom level constraint exactly?

Comment: hi @scai... zoom level constraint is one of the customer's requirements

Comment: I still don't understand where this restriction is coming from, i.e. the library/software you are talking about.

Comment: No, the customer does not want to show to much details (don't get me started on the subject, it's a complete pain in the ***) and therefore limits the max-zoom. BUT he does want me to display the name of all the villages...

Comment: The visibility of labels is defined in the style file. If MapBox doesn't allow to change it then switch to a different OSM tile provider or consider rendering your own OSM tiles.

Comment: Thanks... Already gave MapBox a try, but that did not allow me to get the required result... And afraid building a custom tileset would take to much time and effort